# Why is the MySQL connection getting closed when running from Azure Web Service with Spring boot & JPA

Tags: java, mysql, azure, jpa

I have a web service on Azure, with a spring boot application. This application uses JPA to communicate with a MySQL server.

Running this application on localhost has not given me any issues, but as soon as I published the code to the web service, problems started to arise.

My main problem right now is that whenever I am not using the application for around 5 minutes, the connection to MySQL is getting dropped and it throws an error whenever I try to access it again: `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ConnectionIsClosedException: No operations allowed after connection closed.`

And it never opens another connection, which means I have to restart my app.

I have been looking online for a while now for a solution and have only found that I should try putting `?autoReconnect=true` in my connection string, which unfortunately did not fix this issue.

Hope anyone can help.

Comment: This will be a connection pooling setup issue, so you'll want to describe in more detail what options you are using on your datasource. Pool  min/max connection sizes, timeouts, TTL, idle, inactive and health check config etc. You'll want to check your datasource's docs to see what it accepts and how it can help debug the problem; working around it is might be nice, but you'll want to understand the underlying causes (like say an intermediary node cutting connections at specific times) so they don't impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
```

spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

I found this by digging up more about prod deployments , should work.:)